# How to fix/debug Kali-Linux freeze after starting Virtualbox VM on USB network adapter (Bridged)

Tags: wifi, kali-linux, virtualbox, usb-drive, freeze

**Description of steps to reproduce bug:** 
Step 1 - Connect USB network adapter
Step 2 - Network settings of VM to **Bridged Adapter** and select the wlan from the USB network adapter
Step 3 - Start VM 
Step 4 - Seconds after loading the host OS completely freezes, no input from mouse or keyboard 
Step 5 - Restart laptop from the power button to fix and reboot

Tried these steps with different versions of Virtualbox with no different outcome.
Changing the adapter to another one apart from the USB network adapter fixes the problem, so I assume the problem is not from the VM itself or version of Virtualbox.

**System and app info:**

Virtualbox: `Version 7.0.2 r154219 (Qt5.15.6)`. Installed together with the Extension pack from the original website.

Tried also with `apt-get install virtualbox`

Distro: `5.19.0-kali2-amd64`

USB Network Adapter: `COMFAST CF-953AX`
Chipset: `Mediatek mt7921au`

Looking for either hints/clues of the problem or ways to debug it.